# How to automatically save all org files after marking a repeating item as DONE in the org agenda?

Tags: org-mode

How to automatically save all org files after marking a repeating item as DONE in the org agenda? I'm using this to automatically save my org buffers after every change to TODO status:

```
(advice-add 'org-todo :after (η #'org-save-all-org-buffers))
```

(Where `η` ignores all arguments and calls the given function.)

This however doesn't work for repeating tasks, scheduled like this:

```
SCHEDULED: <2016-04-22 Fri +1d>
```

The org document is still modified after changing the state from TODO to DONE. I've tried a number of hook variables and methods, all without success.

Comment: Are you saying that the file does not get saved?  Or just that it is still marked as modified after the change?  Maybe you could try the hook `org-trigger-hook` instead of using advice.

Comment: @nispio, Tried that, the org buffer is still modified even if I call `org-save-all-buffers` unconditionally in `org-trigger-hook`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, after some investigation it looks like after calling the `org-todo`, the Org mode tries to store some sort of a “note” using the `org-store-log-note` function. So the chain of events is roughly the following:

- `org-todo` is called.
- The advice runs `org-save-all-org-buffers` without problems, everything gets saved.
- If it's a repeating task, `org-store-log-note` gets called, which edits the org file again leaving the buffer in a modified state.

Knowing that, the solutions is obvious—just add an `:after` advice to  the `org-store-log-note` function. My current setup is thus:

```
(advice-add 'org-deadline       :after (η #'org-save-all-org-buffers))
(advice-add 'org-schedule       :after (η #'org-save-all-org-buffers))
(advice-add 'org-store-log-note :after (η #'org-save-all-org-buffers))
(advice-add 'org-todo           :after (η #'org-save-all-org-buffers))
```

This `η` thing is just a helper I defined:

```
(defmacro η (fnc)
  "Return function that ignores its arguments and invokes FNC."
  `(lambda (&rest _rest)
     (funcall ,fnc)))
```

Comment: This would be nice. I tried copying the lines and pasting them. But that 'η' character seems to causing prablem. When pasted, it shows is \267. How do I get 'η'?

Comment: @deshmukh, I have added the definition of that eta helper, hope you find it helpful. (You can use whatever you like instead of η, it's not necessary to use a greek letter after all :-)

Comment: Perfect. I changed η to xx-mu and it worked fine. Thanks. But still curious, how come the same character displays as η in your .emacs and as \267 in mine?